# Why do i need to implement a more general interface if I already implemented a specialized one?

Tags: c#, interface, hierarchy

I have some interfaces and classes for domains and elements:

```
interface IElement {}
class FloatElement : IElement {}

interface IDomain<T> where T: IElement {}
class FloatDomain : IDomain<FloatElement>
{
    public static readonly FloatDomain Instance = new FloatDomain();
}
```

I wrote this

```
IDomain<IElement> foo = FloatDomain.Instance;
```

but got an error:

> (CS0266) "Cannot implicitly convert type [...]. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)"

(Note that, despite the hint "An explicit conversion exists", `FloatDomain.Instance as IDomain<IElement>` will return `null`.)

I already found out that I can work around this problem by making `FloatDomain` also implement `IDomain<IElement>`. **But I would like to know why this workaround is necessary!**

In my understanding, `FloatElement` is a more specialized version of `IElement`, i.e. I can implicitly convert `FloatElement` to `IElement`. Because of that, `IDomain<FloatElement>` is a more specialized version of `IDomain<IElement>`, i.e. I should also be able to implicitly convert `IDomain<FloatElement>` to `IDomain<IElement>`.

Or in other words: in my understanding, `IDomain<IElement>` is like a base class for all other `IDomain<T>` where `T` implements `IElement`, because `T=IElement` is the most general possible case.

Can you point me to my error of reasoning?

Comment: Learn about covariance.

Comment: Look at `List<T>`. Consider casting a `List<string>` to a `List<object>`. Then imagine what happens when a `DefinitelyNotAString` is `Add`ed to that list.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is called **variance**. In C# interfaces are not variant by default, and that's why you're getting compile errors. You can mark your interface as *covariant* or *contravariant* explicitly to make it work:

```
interface IDomain<in T> where T: IElement {}

interface IDomain<out T> where T: IElement {}
```

See [Variance in Generic Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359(v=vs.90).aspx) for more details.